# Raspberry pi kernel 3.2.27 no keyboard detected on boot

Tags: keyboard, kernel, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, boot

I'm trying to cross-compile a driver for Raspberry Pi.
The driver works in kernel 3.2 so I downloaded the 3.2.27 raspberry pi's kernel.

I compiled the kernel as follows:

```
make -j3 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=<dir>/rpi-tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-

make -j3 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=<dir>/rpi-tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- modules

make -j3 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=<dir>/rpi-tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- INSTALL_MOD_PATH=<dir>/modules-3.2.27-linaro/ modules_install
```

Where rpi-tools are the last raspberry's Github tools.

After copy the `Image.img` and /lib folder that includes /firmware and /modules to the SDCard and set the current Image as default, When boot the RaspberryPi shows some troubles related with Network interface and doesn't recognize the USB Keyboard so I can't logging into it.

I tried to modify the .config using `make menuconfig` settings in order to enable the keyboard in `Device Drivers > Input device support` and `Devive Drivers > HID Devices` but nothing works.
I'm using Dell SK-8115 keyboard, supported by RPi.

What options, theoretically, must be enabled in `.config` in kernel compilation for the keyboard use?

If anybody have any idea, your help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The problem was the `cmdline.txt` file that had the flag `dwc_otg.lpm_enable` set to 1 insted of 0.

To edit the file I entered in recovery mode on raspberry boot pressing the Shift key. I edited that file and set the variable to 0. On the reboot the raspberry detected the keyboard.

Source of Raspberry Pi cmdline file: http://elinux.org/RPi_cmdline.txt